# Why is this evaluated to true

Tags: php, boolean, conditional-operator

Can someone please explain me why this line is evaluated to true?

```
false && (true) ? false : true
```

I mean, for what i know about boolean arithmetic, `false && something` is evaluated to false.

Furthermore, this will be evaluated to false, as predicted:

```
true && (true) ? false : true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?:` has lower precedence than `&&` (see the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)) so your expression gets evaluated as

```
(false && (true)) ? false : true
```

=>

```
 false ? false : true
```

=>

```
 true
```

The same applies to your second expression, which is evaluated as

```
(true && (true)) ? false : true
```

=>

```
 true ? false : true
```

=>

```
 false
```

Answer (score 1):

Nick's answer already explained it. However, I think its much easier to understand when we think ternary operators (`:?`) as a short form of `if-else` operation. Therefore,

`false && (true) ? false : true`

statement is same as :

```
if (false && (true)) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true; // the if condition is false, so this will get executed.
}
```

Since the condition inside the `if` is `false` the `else` block is executed and therefore, `true` is returned.